# z-index - img and div as children

Tags: html, css, image, z-index

I have a problem with `z-index`. My `<img>` won't appear behind the `<div>`.

http://cssdesk.com/LGYZm <-- here is the code sample.

The `<img>` and `<div>` are both childs of another `<div>` but the child-div should appear in front of the `<img>`. And in this case `background-image` is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are asking, I looked at the link you provided, are you trying to accomplish what you have at the top and what you have is what's on the bottom?

Regardless, you have this:

```
#bg {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: auto;
}

#childbox2 {
    width: 34%;
    min-height: 500px;
    float: right;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    position: relative;
    z-index: auto;
}
```

Try this:

```
#bg {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#childbox2 {
    width: 34%;
    min-height: 500px;
    float: right;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

your z-index is like you mentioned in your original post, it's basically the stacking order.  However, you have auto for both, the browser may not recognize that (depending on which browser you use)...So rather than having auto for both your child elements, put the actual order you want them to appear as.  So for example, if you want the #bg to be underneath your #childbox2, simply put z-index: 1 for your #bg, and z-index: 2 as your #childbox2 which would mean that your #childbox2 will be on top of #bg....

Also, try not to use % (percentages) for width and height, use pixels - from my experience pixels are better to use ;)  Hope that helps, if so check the checkmark ;)  -  If that doesn't help, please address your question a bit more!

take a look at this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Mcqr/

in the #childbox2 and #bg you have both positions as relative, leave the #bg as relative, but change your #childbox2 position to absolute with top: 0; and right: 0;

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already tried to work with numbers. `z-index: auto` was just another try to solve by natural stacking order. Also i tried to work without % (Which i need for the responsive feature) but it makes no difference at all.

Comment: take a look at the fiddle I provided after I updated my post....You can leave the width and height in %, just change your position attr...Does that help?

Comment: oh sorry i overread that one. I see.. position absolute does the trick. Also top:0 and left:0 is absolut necessery. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not with `z-index` it is with the other parts of your css.

`z-index` won't take an element out of the flow of the document.  It only affects the stacking order.

You need to modify your positioning/layout logic so the two elements align horizontally/vertically the way you want first.

Note: in this case, because the text comes after the picture, the text will naturally be higher in the stacking order.